# .zshenv:2: command not found: rbenv error

Tags: ruby, xcode, cocoapods, zsh, rbenv

ive been trying to load ruby on my macOs Big Sur and i cannot for the life of me figure out how to fix this
i was trying to install cocoapods when it gave me [this](https://gist.github.com/mcls/3118518) error so i follwed [this](https://gist.github.com/mcls/3118518) instruction and im now getting this error \

/Users/kashish/.zshrc:103: command not found: rbenv
➜  ~ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
➜  ~ which rbenv
rbenv not found
➜  ~ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
➜  ~ rbenv doctor
zsh: command not found: rbenv
➜  ~ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshenv

echo 'eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"' >> ~/.zshenv

echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshenv
➜  ~ rbenv doctor
zsh: command not found: rbenv

Comment: How did you install rbenv?

Comment: @halodebug : You obviously forgot to put the directory of `rbenv` into your PATH.